# Objective-C: Can a Cocoa application be a "menu only" app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is a simple "is this possible" in an academic-way question, there's no real purpose for the exercise.

Playing with the [minimalistic example here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html), I came up with the bright idea to remove the window and make the app a "menu-only".

This is the resulting code.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main () {
    [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];

    id menubar = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem new] autorelease];
    [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
    [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];

    id appMenu = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];

    id quitTitle = [@"Quit " stringByAppendingString:appName];
    id quitMenuItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:quitTitle
        action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"] autorelease];

    [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
    [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];

    // Window code deleted

    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [NSApp run];

    return 0;
}
```

This code works, however, getting the menu to show up or "focus" is somewhat erratic.  It's possible to right click the icon in the dock and get the context sensitive menu, and sometimes clicking on the icon will show a menu that'll all me to quit the app normally.  Note the word *sometimes*.  I haven't yet figured out if there are any specific triggers to make the menu show up.

Can this code be edited to make the (mostly empty) menu show up predictably, or have the focus?  Can this be done without any window whatsoever?

In Windows, it at least used to be possible to make an icon-only program, where the window to be drawn was the minimized icon and there was no way to "restore" a proper window.  If a similar technique works in Cocoa, I'd call that "cheating but acceptable solution."

Comment: That's already part of the app.  From `id menubar` and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sometimes" is probably simply that you're clicking long enough to trigger the delayed display of the menu when holding the left mouse button down. The actual display of the menu when clicking on the icon in the Dock is not controlled in any way by the application itself, so you're barking up the wrong tree.

There's nothing special at all about what you're trying to do. No application is required to ever have a window open. If you don't want any windows, fine; just don't create any. But if that application is going to appear in the Dock (as is standard), then that application is going to be "activatable" and have a menu bar (which certainly could be empty, but still exists). Such an application would be abnormal and feel "broken" to every Mac user, though.

Instead, the appropriate thing to do is create an application that *does not* appear in the Dock (by using `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory`), and has a global menu (called a "Status Item") in the menu bar. See `NSStatusItem`.